# How to add pseudo class in styled components with normal object ( not literal )?

Tags: styled-components

I have a styled `button` :

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export const Button = styled.button({
  width: "100%",
  height: "3rem",
  border: "none",
  cursor: "pointer",
  fontSize: "1em",
  fontFamily: ["inter", "sans-serfi"],
  fontWeight: 500,
  backgroundColor: "#1F75FE",
  color: "#FFF",
  borderRadius: "0.5em",
});
```

and I want to add `hover` pseudo-class but I could not do that. However, with literal object, it could be like :

```
export const Button = styled.button`
  &: hover{}
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

By using an object for styled components, you can pass styles to Hover and other pseudo classes. Good luck!

```
const CustomButton = styled.button({
    backgroundColor: '#1F75FE',
    color: '#FFF',
    ':hover': {
        color: 'red',
        backgroundColor: 'black',
    },
    ':active': {
        color: 'green',
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    },
});
```